# Generating random sequences in R

Tags: r, sequence

I wish to generate a random string of letters (a, c, g, t). I accomplish this with the following lines of R code:

```
nucl <- letters[c(1, 3, 7, 20)] # generate letters

length.seqs <- 10

res <- sample(nucl, size = length.seqs, replace = TRUE) # sample with replacement to generate sequence
```

However, I do not want there to be consecutive runs of the strings "taa", "tag" and "tga" within the final sequence. Note that the order of letters in these substrings is important. For example, the substring "atg"  would be OK to have in the final sequence, but "tag" would not be OK.

What is the simplest way to generate a random string of a given length (length.seqs) without substrings "taa", "tag", "tga"?

To illustrate, the sequence ATGTGCTTAG would not be OK since there is a TAG at the end. However the sequence ATGTGCTTAT would be OK.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Some thiings you mentioned in the comment is missing in the post.  Does the order matter for `taa`, `tag` `tga` ?  Or is it only the order of sequence 'taa', 'tag', 'tga'?  That means 'tga', 'tag', 'taa' can occur?

Comment: No. "tag", "tga" and "taa" cannot occur in the final sequence

Comment: it is a bit unclear in the post

Comment: Hopefully it's a bit clearer now with an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `grep()`.

```
M1 <- M[- c(grep("taa", M), grep("tag", M), grep("tga", M))]
```

or, a little nicer

```
M1 <- M[- grep(paste(c("taa", "tag", "tga"), collapse="|"), M)]
```

***Result***

```
> head(M1)
[1] "ttctgggagg" "cgtccttacg" "ccatcttgtg" "aaacagacga" "gaattgcggg" "gaacttggga"
```

***Data***

```
set.seed(42)
nucl <- c("a", "c", "g", "t")
n <- 1e5
length.seqs <- 10
M <- replicate(n, paste0(sample(nucl, length.seqs, replace = TRUE), collapse=""))
```

Comment: Great! Now then on Stack Overflow it's common to mark the answer as accepted and to gain **+2** reputation. Click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from hollow to green (see [help](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/371738)).

Answer (score 0):

Here's a straightforward function to generate such a sequence.  The R gurus can probably find ways to make it more efficient. (The function assumes that `seqlen` is at least 3.)

```
generate <- function(seqlen) {

    choices <- c('a', 'c', 'g', 't')
    choices.ta <- c('c', 't')
    choices.tg <- c('c', 'g', 't')

    vec <- vector("list", seqlen)
    vec[1:2] <- sample(choices, size=2, replace=TRUE)

    for (i in 3:seqlen) {
        if ((vec[i-2] == 't') && (vec[i-1] == 'a')) {
            vec[i] <- sample(choices.ta, size=1)
        }
        else if ((vec[i-2] == 't') && (vec[i-1] == 'g')) {
            vec[i] <- sample(choices.tg, size=1)
        }
        else {
            vec[i] <- sample(choices, size=1)
        }
    }

    # Collapse vec to a string.
    res <- paste(vec, collapse='')
    return(res)
}
```

For example,

```
> generate(10)
[1] "gtatcggcgg"
> generate(100)
[1] "aagcaactctaccgagattcatcttacgatggacggggtttccctacatcacttggggcactcgggctggcgcacatggatggcggtgcgtccaaattgc"
> generate(100)
[1] "tgtttcgcacctacaagcatttctatacttcgaatatatcaaaagagtgggcgtcctgcccgaccatcggccctcgtggctgggctttcactgcaaagga"
```